# Convert a Normal Postgres Database to PostGis Database

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis

I have a normal postgres database with lots of geo coded data. This is just present two columns as latitude and longitude.

I want to convert this database to PostGIs database. Can anyone suggest me a way to convert the database i have? I don't want to create a new postgis tempalte based database and then move the whole data one by one.

Comment: The PostGIS docs discuss how to "spatially enable" a database. Once you've done that you just add PostGIS columns with the appropriate PostGIS functions, use `UPDATE`s to copy the basic geo data into the PostGIS columns, and drop the old columns.

Comment: If you are running PostgreSQL 9.1+, you don't need to bother with the template database. Just create a database and then on the SQL view in pgAdmin, type and run

CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
That will spatially enable your database.

Source : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/how-to-create-postgis-template

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, make sure PostGIS is installed on the system, then [create](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) a PostGIS extension for the database using:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Next, spatially enable each table with a geometry column and populate the column with the long/lat data points:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point,4326);
UPDATE mytable SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326);
```

Also consider using the [geography](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html) type:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN geog geography(Point,4326);
UPDATE mytable SET geog = ST_MakePoint(long, lat)::geography;
```

Comment: I have the postgis Ubuntu packages installed, yet running that gets me "ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory"

Comment: @Cerin I'd notify the package manager with additional details

Comment: Just tried this again in Ubuntu 14, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is older... but I'd add something to address a previous issue:

@Cerin, make sure you apt-get install postgresql-x.x-postgis-2.1, not just apt-get install postgis. I had that issue before as well

Comment: I get the same error as @Cerin but saying it can't find "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis.control" (I've a Debian with installed postgresql-9.4 and postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 )